# Perl6: is there a phaser that runs only when you fall out of a loop?

Tags: raku

Take this sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

use v6.c;

ROLL:
for 1..10 -> $r {
    given (1..6).roll {
        when 6 {
            say "Roll $r: you win!";
            last ROLL;
        }
        default {
            say "Roll $r: sorry...";
        }
    }
    LAST {
        say "You either won or lost - this runs either way";
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to distinguish falling out of the loop from explicitly saying `last`.
Ideally, there'd be a phaser for this, but as far as I can find, there is only `LAST` which runs in either case.

Is there an elegant way to do this?  (Elegant, so without adding a `$won` variable.)

Comment: Won't work - `$r == 10` whether you lose or win in the 10th roll.

Comment: The three most annoying problems in programming are encoding issues and off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're dealing with Perl, so *There's More Than One Way To Do It*; one of them is using the topic variable `$_` to keep the value so we can easily match against it repeatedly:

```
constant N = 5;
for flat (1..6).roll xx * Z 1..N -> $_, $n {
    print "roll $n: $_ ";

    when 6 {
        put "(won)";
        last;
    }

    default {
        put "(lost)";
    }

    LAST {
        print "result: ";
        when 6 { put "winner :)" }
        default { put "loser :(" }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is certainly a working solution.  Elegant?  I guess that is in the eye of the beholder, but it took me a few minutes to figure out the second line, so not in my eye.  ;)

Comment: @mscha: you could write the loop header using less magic, eg `for 1..N -> $n { $_ = (1..6).roll;`

Comment: in fact, I should probably edit my answer; I find assigning to `$_` explicitly instead of implicitly with a topicalizer (eg `given`) somewhat ugly (probably because it's imperative instead of functional), but if it makes the code easier to read, I can live with that

Comment: note that using `$_` explicitly has scoping issues, so I'll roll back to my previous version...

Comment: You should be using `(1..6).roll(*) Z 1..N` as that is probably going to be more performant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it.  Elegant?  I think reasonably so.  I wish there were a separate phaser for this, though.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

use v6.c;

constant MAX_ROLLS = 10;

ROLL:
for 1..MAX_ROLLS+1 -> $r {
    last ROLL if $r > MAX_ROLLS;

    given (1..6).roll {
        when 6 {
            say "Roll $r: you win!";
            last ROLL;
        }
        default {
            say "Roll $r: sorry...";
        }
    }

    LAST {
        say "You lost, better luck next time!" if $r > MAX_ROLLS;
    }
}
```